# Excel 2007, value distribution

Tags: excel

I am working with Excel 2007, I have 10 values in names (lets 5 masonry, 3 RC, 1 Stone and 1 Wood), I want to distribute These values two 100 other cells with the same frequency. Can anybody help me with any formula?

Comment: So do you want to generate 50 masonry cells, 30 RC etc. in random order? Or 100 cells with probability 0.5 that they are masonry, 0.3 that they are RC etc. (in which case you wouldn't expect to get exactly 50, 30, etc.)

Comment: @Zippy, I have tryed frequency but i doest give the Distribution in randow way to the other 90 cells.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe, I want in 100 cells with the probability of 0,5 masonry, 0,3 Rc ecc. Still in random way.

Comment: Sounds like [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a), [COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a), [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) and some basic maths should do it. Glad to 'help me [you] with any formula' but I don't see 'any formula'.

Comment: @Jeeped, already tryed with those, steel no result.

Comment: ... and yet you still refuse to show what you've come up with (working or not). Odd that.

Comment: @Jepped, In the first example I have showed only a simple case. Currently I am working with GIS related softs which takes into account 30000 cells in a row. Ist not so simple as it Looks.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given us, if you had the original ten values in (say) A2:A11, it would be sufficient to use the following formula copied down to pick one of them with the same frequency:-

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$11,RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

As mentioned, you won't in general get exactly 50,30,10,10 values doing it this way.

You could make it a bit more general by using COUNTA to get the number of values (assuming there is a header in A1 then a list of values followed by blanks):-

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(2,COUNTA(A:A)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this formula helped alot.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I really wanted.